Where can I find detailed information on the operation of virtual machine protectors?
I need documents for a degree thesis about the functioning of virtual machine protectors, more specifically about VMProtect and the protection process through virtualization and/or mutation
I have investigated web pages, but not much information appears. I would appreciate it if you could tell me if you know where I can get that information.

Requests for off-site resources are off topic here. Please see the [help].
